# How to share data between components in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, components

I have two components category.ts and register.ts. Category.ts contains category_id. I want to share this data to register.ts. How should I do it.
**category.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { RegisterPage } from '../register/register';
import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'category.html'
  // selector: 'page-home',

})
export class CategoryPage {
    public category_id = 2;
    category:  Object[];
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
        this.category = [{cid:1,cname:'Doctor',img:'../../assets/imgs/doctor.png'},{cid:2,cname:'Phsiotherapist',img:'../../assets/imgs/physiotherapist.png'},{cid:3,cname:'Medical Store',img:'../../assets/imgs/medicalStore.png'}]; 
    }
    gotoRegister() {
      this.navCtrl.push(RegisterPage);
    }
```

**register.ts**

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ApiService } from '../../services/api.service';
import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'register.html'
  // selector: 'page-home',

})
export class RegisterPage {
    public user:Object = {};
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private validatorService: ValidatorService,private apiService: ApiService) {
    }

    registerUser() {
     console.log(category_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please specify that this is an Ionic question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a data  model class where you store the data using set and get methods. You set the data in Category.ts and get the data in register.ts.

```
DataModelClass{
  public someData;

  setSomeData(someData){
     this.someData = someData;
  }
  getSomeData(){
      return this.someData;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is total 4 way to share data between component.

[Four way to share data b/w component](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/)

I am giving you exmple for 4th method.

You Need to create one data-sharing service.

**==> data-sharing.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
@Injectable()
export class DataSharingService {

  private someDataSource = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  currentSomeDataChanges = this.someDataSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  someDataChanges(data) {
    this.someDataSource.next(data);
  }
}
```

Save Your category_id in service

**== >category.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { RegisterPage } from '../register/register';
import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';
import { DataSharingService } from 'data-sharing'

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'category.html'
})

export class CategoryPage {
    public category_id = 2;
    category:  Object[];
    constructor(
        public navCtrl: NavController,
        public data:DataSharingService
    ) {
        this.category = [{cid:1,cname:'Doctor',img:'../../assets/imgs/doctor.png'},{cid:2,cname:'Phsiotherapist',img:'../../assets/imgs/physiotherapist.png'},{cid:3,cname:'Medical Store',img:'../../assets/imgs/medicalStore.png'}]; 

        this.data.someDataChanges(category_id);

    }
    gotoRegister() {
      this.navCtrl.push(RegisterPage);
    }
}
```

Get Your cetegory_id from service

**==> register.ts**

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ApiService } from '../../services/api.service';
import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';
import { DataSharingService } from 'data-sharing'

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'register.html'
  // selector: 'page-home',

})
export class RegisterPage {
    public user:Object = {};
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private validatorService: ValidatorService,private apiService: ApiService,public data:DataSharingService) {
        this.data.currentSomeDataChanges.subscribe(categoryId => {
            console.log(categoryId)
        });
    }

    registerUser() {
     console.log(category_id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can share data between Angular components using following methods

1. Using angular Services (the easy way)
2. Use State Management Library like [NgRx](https://github.com/ngrx/store)